# Can not Install on a Dell Latitude laptop --

Tags: boot, system-installation, password-recovery, administration

The laptop always boots winXP and requests an Administrator password.  I went into the setup where I attempted to reset all passwords and the start up order but the Admin password is still demanded.   I can't get a Ubuntu boot from the cd drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information. I have a couple of suggestions but the only way you can work through this is if you provide more information such as: model number, bios image, etc...

1. Usually you boot from the BIOS into the Ubuntu CD so you need to change the bios boot options. Based on the fact that you are changing the OS from winXP to Ubuntu means that you don't need to worry about UEFI. Make sure that you put the CDROM boot ahead of your Hard Drive boot and you should be good once you **save and exit** (usually F10 or some variant).
2. If you have an administration password for the bios I believe you can remove that by unplugging the power cord and battery for a certain amount of time before it wipes the password clean (Not too sure on this point but Google it). Maybe follow these [instructions](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001302.htm)